# Dúvida implementação Banco SQL

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados

Estou criando um controle de produtos de uma empresa, no qual precisamos gerar códigos sequenciais para os produtos a medida que forem cadastrados, vendemos produtos digitais, logo não tem quantidade física. A princípio pensei em utilizar um campo de auto incremento, porém temos outro problema: Vendemos os produtos por pacotes, ou seja, necessitaria de várias baixas simultâneas, pois de 1 em 1 não faria muito sentido ou levaria mais tempo. 
Também ouvi falar sobre a função SEQUENCE (Implementada no SQL Server 2012).

Qual seria a melhor sugestão para um banco de dados?

A interface pensei em utilizar C#, bem como em utilizar SQL Server para a base de dados.

O que vocês me sugerem?

Comment: Uma chave primária é um campo que identifica de forma única o que a tabela implementa, pode ser um número sequencial , um código etc. , qual a relação disto com a baixa ?

Comment: Gustavo, você quer criar um controle para criação do código do produto ou controlar um numero único para cada produto (numero de série)?  Eu tenho esses dois controles, a minha solução foi criar uma tabela com o controle das sequences.  Essa é a sua duvida?  Se for, posso detalhar a minha solução.

Comment: Bom dia,
Resolvi o problema colocando uma chave primária com auto incremento mesmo alinhada com outra para ter um prefixo para diferenciar. Muito obrigado.

Comment: @GustavoFerreiradaSilva Se você encontrou a solução por gentileza poste-a como resposta. Obrigado.